# Directlabels outside plotting area / Disable directlabels' auto-resize

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Package 'directlabels' apparently by default tries to fit each label inside the normal plotting area by reducing label font size.

Below, `Label for One`, `Label for Two` and `Label for Threeeeeeeeee` should all have the same font size and it is ok if the labels run out of the plotting area (since `clip` is disabled for custom annotations to show).

In fact, I might want to set `xlim=c(1,3)` and the labels should be entirely outside the plotting area. The left column of images below is for `xlim=c(1,3.4)`, the right colum for `xlim=c(1,3)`.

I learned that `cex` can be used to reset a label's fontsize, but it seems to conflict with the package's label separation algorithm. The top row of images below is for no `cex`, the bottom row for `cex=1`.

It would be great to find a way to have labels don't overlap, be the same font size, and that works with `xlim=c(1,3)` and `xlim=c(1,3.4)`.

[image]

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)

df=data.frame(
  x = 1:3,
  One=c(12, 8, 13),
  Two=c(13, 7, 11),
  Threeeeeeeeee=c(11, 9, 11))

df.d.melt = melt(df[,c("x","One","Two","Threeeeeeeeee")], id.vars="x")
df.d.melt$variable1 = df.d.melt$variable
levels(df.d.melt$variable1) = paste("","Lable for",levels(df.d.melt$variable1))

p = ggplot(df.d.melt, aes(x=x, y=value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.1) +
  geom_text(aes(x =3.4, y=8, label="Custom Outside\nChart Annotation"), show_guide=FALSE) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(1,3.4)) +
  geom_dl(aes(label=variable1), method=list("last.qp", cex=1), show_guide=FALSE) + 
  theme(legend.position="top",plot.margin = unit(c(0, 4, 0, 0), "cm")) 

p1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
p1$layout$clip[p1$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(p1)
```

Comment: the plot of the question is confusing. The code you give is not for a faceted plot. Can you please edit your question and precise your final desired plot?

Comment: @agstudy: This was pasted together in MSPaint. Sorry, I have not done faceted plots for a long time. The code shown is for chart on the bottom left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution is to attach the labels to additional invisible short lines lines at the left side of the chart (e.g. defined over `x=1` to `x=1.001`) and use directlabels' `trans_new` to move the annotations to the desired x-value.

Answer (score 1):

By default, directlabels assumes you want to have readable labels INSIDE the plotting region, so it reduces the text size so the label fits inside using [reduce.cex.lr](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/docs/utility.function/posfuns/reduce.cex.lr.html). Labels outside the plot can be accomplished by defining a custom Positioning Method that does not reduce the text size, e.g.

```
do.not.reduce <-
  list(cex=2, "last.points", "calc.boxes",
       qp.labels("y", "bottom", "top", make.tiebreaker("x", "y")))

WithLegend <- ggplot(df.d.melt, aes(x=x, y=value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.1) +
  geom_text(aes(x =3.4, y=8, label="Custom Outside\nChart Annotation")) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(1,3)) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 4, 0, 0), "cm"))
WithLabels <- direct.label(WithLegend, "do.not.reduce")
GTable <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(WithLabels))
GTable$layout$clip[GTable$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(GTable)
```